# Laravel local subdomain url call

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, wamp, subdomain

I have a laravel application which I Extended with this route:

```
Route::domain('{account}'.'.app.test')->group(function () {
    return '{account}'."-test";
});
```

I am using laragon (wamp stack) so `localhost/myapp` Maps tp `app.test`

but how do I call a random subdomain locally in my browser?

If I for instance try to call `subdomain.app.test` I get a page not found message from telekom (live in Germany).

How can I configure this to make it work locally?

Comment: `'{account}.'.app.test'` looks wrong

Comment: @Kerbholz updated it to '{account}'.'.app.test', still not working

Answer (score -1):

The domain syntax should be:

```
Route::domain('{account}.example.com')->group(function() {
     Route::get('user/{id}', function($account, $id) {
        //code
     });
});
```

Please refer to the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing